# Javascript value is not changing

Tags: javascript

I've created a Javascript class called `myClass` with two methods in it: `method1` and `method2`. `method1` sets a value to a property called `X`, `method2` sets another value to the same property and alerts it.

The problem is I run the code and nothing alerts. **Any ideas why is this happening?**

My code is below:

```
var myClass = function(classParamObject){

   this.method1 = function() {

       classParamObject.X = 'TEST';

   };

   this.method2 = function() {

       // Even if I change the value of X to 'NEW VALUE', it is not changing
       classParamObject.X = 'NEW VALUE';

       // This alerts as 'TEST'
       alert(classParamObject.X);
   };

  this.method1();
  this.method2();

}
```

Comment: I dont see the word new anywhere. Other than the literal.

Comment: Are you calling your class from somewhere?

Comment: Since running that code on its own does nothing and adding `foo = new myClass()` throws an error, I think you need to update this question to include something that's actually executable.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/SmgmQ/1/

Comment: @Dancrumb you need to do `var foo = new myClass({});` and pass it an object

Comment: @SmartLemon - thanks, I got there a minute after posting that comment :)... however, OP still needs to update question to show how they're using this object... as it stands, the code does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to instantiate your class for the whole thing to run: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94zQH/1/))

```
var myClass = function(classParamObject){

   this.method1 = function() {

       classParamObject.X = 'TEST';

   };

   this.method2 = function() {

       // Even if I change the value of X to 'NEW VALUE', it is not changing
       classParamObject.X = 'NEW VALUE';

       // This alerts as 'TEST'
       alert(classParamObject.X);
   };

    this.method1(); 
    this.method2();

}

// Now the important part:
var myTest = new myClass({}); // initiate with object
```